# Ingredient has many sub-ingredients modelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I've got a `Recipe` model, and an `Ingredient` model. Right now a Recipe
`has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients` and Ingredient `has_and_belongs_to_many
:recipes`.

Because an Ingredient could conceivably be made up of other Ingredients, I'm
trying to do a self-join on that model, like so:

```
has_many :components, class_name: 'Ingredient', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
belongs_to :parent,   class_name: 'Ingredient'
```

Now, this works, but each Ingredient can only have one parent, e.g., Mayonnaise
is in the "Crab Cakes" Ingredient which is part of a Recipe, but then it can't
be an Ingredient in the "Spicy Mayo" Ingredient of some other Recipe
simultaneously.

What I'm trying to get is an interface like this:

```
r = Recipe.create(name: "Jumbo Lump Crab Cakes")
r.ingredients << Ingredient.create(name: "Crab Cakes")
r.ingredients[0].ingredients # => []
r.ingredients[0].ingredients.create(name: "Mayonnaise")
r.ingredients[0].ingredients # => [#<Ingredient id: 2, name: "Mayonnaise">]
r.ingredients[0].ingredients[0].ingredients.create(name: "Eggs")
r.ingredients[0].ingredients[0].ingredients # => [#<Ingredient id: 3, name: "Eggs">]

Ingredient.last               # => #<Ingredient id: 3, name: "Eggs">
Ingredient.last.parent        # => #<Ingredient id: 2, name: "Mayonnaise">
Ingredient.last.parent.parent # => #<Ingredient id: 1, name: "Crab Cakes">

# Bonus points if a child ingredient can "walk up" its heritage tree to the recipe:
Ingredient.last.recipe        # => #<Recipe id: 1>
```

Obviously I need an association table to store ingredient/sub-ingredient
relationships, but that's about as far as I've figured out. I've tried various
feats of `source` and `through` wizardry with no luck.

I also messed around with a polymorphic association, where everything has a
parent and it's either of type Ingredient or of type Recipe, but couldn't get
that to work out with the interface I wanted.

Comment: And you didn't mention that a recipe can be an ingredient for another recipe, or a sub-ingredient for an ingredient.

Comment: I guess you could say an Ingredient that has sub-ingredients is just a "recipe" for making that ingredient, but that's more of a semantics thing. It's not necessary to me that a Recipe can have sub-recipes.

Comment: Think in terms of a classic bill-of-materials - don't get hung up on the terminology. Mayonnaise for instance may itself be made from egg yolks, oil, perhaps mustard, pickles and so on. Even such a fundamental 'ingredient' as 'egg' may be viewed as constructed of 'yolk' and 'white'. What you are referring to as 'recipe' is an association of `ingredients` and `assembly instructions` which itself may be a sub-assembly, in the same way as 'aircraft' is assembled from 'screws, bolts and washers' and a few other things - ina particular way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it figured out. Ended up using a modified version of [this post](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through).

```
create_table :ingredients do |t| # :hunts
  t.references :parent # :predator
  t.references :child  # :prey
end

add_index :ingredients, :parent_id # :hunts, :predator_id
add_index :ingredients, :child_id  # :hunts, :prey_id

create_table :components do |t| # :animals
  t.string :name
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base # Animal
  has_many :parentage, foreign_key: 'parent_id',
                       class_name: 'Ingredient',
                       dependent: :destroy

  has_many :children, through: :parentage

  has_many :progeny, foreign_key: 'child_id',
                     class_name: 'Ingredient',
                     dependent: :destroy

  has_many :parents, through: :progeny
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base # Hunt
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Component'
  belongs_to :child,  class_name: 'Component'
end
```

Fairly happy with the parentage/progeny naming.